# Add texte before headings numbers (KOMA)

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I'm using the KOMA class scrbook, and trying to add some text before any section and subsection title. Like that :

`\section{Hello !}` must display `Section 1 : Hello !` (1 is the normal counter). The same with "Subsection # :" before any section title.

So I tried the following code :

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Section \@arabic\c@section}
```

The snag is that I want to have those section/subsection title **centered**, so I added the parameter \centering when defining my headings font :

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\HeadingFont\centering}
```

But with this code, *only the very name of the section is centered*, but not the prefix "section 1". It is a problem when I have long titles, the page lacks balance. Can I try with `\othersectionlevelsformat`, like indicated in the manual, or have you another solution ?

[image]

As a bonus, have you a quick way to fix the table of contents, because the dots are encroaching the added text. I manually tried something with :

```
\renewcommand\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4.2em}}
```

Comment: You are asking quite a lot here, please split that to different questions, each one with a minimal working example to make the question understandable and the problem reproducable.

Comment: `\let\raggedsectin\centering`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update** regarding **KOMA-Script version 3.28**:

Redefine `\raggedsection` and `\sectionlinesformat` to center the section titles including the numbers:

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
%\providecommand*\Ifstr{\ifstr}% needed up to and including KOMA-Script version 3.27, see https://komascript.de/faq_deprecatedif
\usepackage{blindtext}
\let\raggedsection\centering
\let\raggedchapter\raggedright

\renewcommand\sectionformat{Section~\thesection:\enskip}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{Subsection~\thesubsection:\enskip}
\renewcommand\subsubsectionformat{Subsubsection~\thesubsection:\enskip}

\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{#3#4}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  dynnumwidth,
  entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{Sect.}
]{default}{section}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  dynnumwidth,
  entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{Subs.}
]{default}{subsection}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  dynnumwidth,
  entrynumberformat=\entrywithprefix{Subsubs.}
]{default}{subsubsection}

\newcommand*\entrywithprefix[2]{%
  \def\autodot{}%
  \mbox{#1\,#2:}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\blindtext
\section{First section}
\blindtext
\subsection{a rabbit subsection with quite a few words to make it
extra long not only because ducks are so cute}
\Blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

---

**Original answers (2015):**

You could redefine `\raggedsection`, `\raggedchapter` and `\othersectionlevelsformat` (for version 3.17 or newer see the update below):

```
\let\raggedsection\centering
\let\raggedchapter\raggedright

\renewcommand\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{Section~#3:\enskip}{%
    \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{Subsection~#3:\enskip}{%
      #3\autodot\enskip}}}
```

To centr the section and subsection titles including the numbers use

```
\makeatletter
\addtokomafont{section}{\let\@hangfrom\relax}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\let\@hangfrom\relax}
\makeatother
```

[image]

If the entries in the table of contents should also be changed redefine `\addsectiontocentry` and `\addsubsectiontocentry` additionally:

```
\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#2}}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{section}{Sect.\,#1:}{#2}}}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{}{#2}}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{Subs.\,#1:}{#2}}}
```

To get more space for the numbers you could enlarge the `tocnumwidth` for `section` and `subsection` (needs the up to date KOMA-Script version 3.15)

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=5em]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=5.5em]{subsection}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\let\raggedsection\centering
\let\raggedchapter\raggedright

\makeatletter
\addtokomafont{section}{\let\@hangfrom\relax}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\let\@hangfrom\relax}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{Section~#3:\enskip}{%
    \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{Subsection~#3:\enskip}{%
      #3\autodot\enskip}}}

\renewcommand\addsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{section}{}{#2}}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{section}{Sect.\,#1:}{#2}}}
\renewcommand\addsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{}{#2}}{%
    \addtocentrydefault{subsection}{Subs.\,#1:}{#2}}}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=5em]{section}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[tocnumwidth=5.5em]{subsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\blindtext
\section{First section}
\blindtext
\subsection{a rabbit subsection with quite a few words to make it
extra long not only because ducks are so cute}
\Blindtext
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

**Update regarding `\othersectionlevelsformat` and KOMA-Script Version 3.17 or newer**

Note that KOMA-Script Version 3.17 uses `\sectionformat`, `\subsectionformat` etc. instead `\othersectionlevelsformat`. So you have to redefine this commands instead of `\othersectionlevelsformat`

```
\renewcommand\sectionformat{Section~\thesection:\enskip}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{Subsection~\thesubsection:\enskip}
```

If the code should work with both the older versions (3.15 and 3.16) and version 3.17 or newer you can use

```
\renewcommand\othersectionlevelsformat[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}{Section~#3:\enskip}{%
    \ifstr{#1}{subsection}{Subsection~#3:\enskip}{%
      #3\autodot\enskip}}}

\providecommand*\sectionformat}{}
\providecommand*{\subsectionformat}{}
\renewcommand\sectionformat{Section~\thesection:\enskip}
\renewcommand\subsectionformat{Subsection~\thesubsection:\enskip}
```

Comment: @gaspalet I would prefer this solution.

Comment: Great work ! I added \let\raggedchapter\raggedright not to touch the behavior of the chapter.
Yet my main problem remains : I added a picture in my first post to show what I mean. I want the hole section title to be centered, not just what is entered in \section{}.
Any idea ?

Comment: @Gaspalet I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a thousand times, that's perfect ! An jeweler's work ;) Thanks too @Johannes_B !

Answer (score 1):

I have *absolutely* no idea what you want to achieve, but this should give you a good start:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\itshape}
\let\raggedsection\centering
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Section \@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{Subsection \@arabic\c@subsection}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{gaspalet}
\section{a duck section}
\label{duck}
\subsection{a rabbit subsection with quite a few words to make it
extra long not only because ducks are so cute}
See \ref{duck}


\end{document}
```

[image: gaspaletToc]

[image: gaspaletDoc]

Comment: Great, that's close to what I was looking after ! I still have two problems. At first, I don't want chapter titles to be centered. The second issue is more tricky, and it was why I looked for help : in the solution you gave, only the words "a rabbit subsection...so cute" are centered, "Subsection 1" is kinda put aside on the left. I want the hole to be centered. I added a photo in my first post to show what I mean :)

Comment: @Gaspalet `\let\raggedchapter\raggedright`